# Google is not indexing the main domain

Tags: domains, google-index

We have a main domain called `www.riya.travel`. If a user visits `riya.travel` from India it will redirect to the subdomain `in.riya.travel` . If a user visits `riya.travel` from another country, it will redirect to `us.riya.travel`.

I want to index `riya.travel` in Google. We installed Google Analytics and Webmaster Tools and submitted a sitemap. I want to index the sub main to my main domain. Is this possible? If yes, then how should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are redirecting all traffic to either us.riya.travel or in.riya.travel, then it means Google bot will also get redirected, this is the most likely reason your main domain is not getting indexed.

As per Google's guidelines, you should avoid automatic redirection based on a users location.

[Read more on Google's guidelines on multi lingual sites.](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192)

Comment: +1 for avoiding automatic redirection based on a users location.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of redirect do you use?
If 301 it impossible, because of googlebot can't reach it (main domain). He is redirected as a usual visitor. Even more, he will not index it because of 301 redirect means "moved permanently" and it is not necessary in including it to index.